# Передача указателей в функцию C++

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, ссылки, параметры

Вопрос по C++. При передаче обычной переменной в функцию создается, как я понимаю, её копия. А что происходит, когда мы передаем указатель? Создается ли копия указателя или нет?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Если у вас объявлена функция с параметром, как, например,

```
void f( T t );
```

где `T` - это некоторый тип, и эта функция вызывается с некоторым выражением, переданным ей в качестве аргумента, как

```
f( exp );
```

то инициализацию параметра можно представить следующим образом

```
void f( /* T t */ )
{
    T t = exp;
    //...
```

то есть параметр - это локальная переменная функции, которая инициализируется тем выражением, которое передано функции в качестве аргумента.  Следовательно изменения параметра никак не сказываются на исходном аргументе, ели только тип `T` не является ссылочным типом.

Сравните две функции

```
void f( int *p )
{
    p = new int( 10 );
}

void g( int * &p )
{
    p = new int( 10 );
}
```

и их вызов

```
int main()
{
    int *p = nullptr;

    f( p );

    if ( p == nullptr ) std::cout << "p is equal to nullptr" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "p is not equal to nullptr" << std::endl;

    g( p );

    if ( p == nullptr ) std::cout << "p is equal to nullptr" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "p is not equal to nullptr" << std::endl;

    delete p;
}
```

В этом примере при вызове функции `f` имеет место утечка памяти, так как память, распределенная в функции, не освобождается. Параметр функции - локальная переменная `p` - при выходе из функции удаляется, и тем самым адрес выделенной динамически памяти будет утерян.

У функции `g` параметр имеет ссылочный тип, то есть эта ссылка на переданный функции аргумент. Поэтому функция имеет дело с исходным аргументом и меняет его в своем теле, присваивая ему адрес выделенной памяти.

Также можно передать указатель на указатель, если требуется изменить исходный указатель в функции. Например,

```
void h( int **p )
{
    *p = new int( 10 );
}
```

Вызов функции будет выглядеть как

```
h( &p );
```

Answer (score 7):

Создается.

Внутри функции вы можете присвоить указателю другое значение и это не повлияет на внешнюю переменную.

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int* p) {
  p = nullptr;
  std::cout << "inside: " << p << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  int v;
  int* p = &v;
  std::cout << "before: " << p << std::endl;
  foo(p);
  std::cout << "after:  " << p << std::endl;
}
```

> before: 0x7ffd4a1eba94
>   inside: 0
>   after:  0x7ffd4a1eba94

[Рабочий пример](https://repl.it/Ew6s).